# Proving continunity for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^6\to \mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have a function that goes as following

$$f:\mathbb{R^6}\to\mathbb{R}^6\\(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3)\mapsto\frac{x^2_2+y^2_2-x_1x_2+x_1x_3+y_1y_2+y_1y_3-x_2x_3-y_2y_3}{(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2}$$

since we're working with reals, it suffices to show that if $f=\frac{h}{g}$, if $h$ is and $g$ is continuous then $f$ is also continuous. But I already struggle to show that any of them are continuous. Let $p=(u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2,v_3)\in \mathbb{R}^6$ then $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3)\in h^{-1}(u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ I will also denote $u_0=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $v_0=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and we have $p_u<h(u_0,v_0)<p_v$ meaning we can find a $\varepsilon >0$ such that

$$p_u+\varepsilon <h(u_0,v_0)<p_v-\varepsilon$$

let $z=(u_0,v_0)$ then we have $B\left(z,\varepsilon\right)\subset h^{-1}(u_0,v_0)$, now I would introduce $(u_0',v_0')\in B(z,\varepsilon)$ then we would have $|u_0-u_0'|<\varepsilon$ same for $|v_0-v_0'|<\varepsilon$. But somehow this does not feel right at all. If I can show that $B(z,\varepsilon)\subset h^{-1}(u_0,v_0)\implies h^{-1}(u_0,v_0)$ is open and hence $h$ is cotninuous..... I want to prove continuity using open sets, but I don't see how with this given function.

Comment: The function is going to $\Bbb R$ not $\Bbb R^6$. Not that it matters for the argument.

Answer (score 3):

*This was meant to be a comment but those do not accept lists.*

1. Projections are continuous, i.e. functions of the form $\mathbf{x} \to x_i.$
2. Sums, products of continuous is continuous. Quotients of continuous are continuous wherever they are defined. (That is, wherever the denominator/bottom is not zero.)
3. Thus, polynomials and rational functions are continuous.
4. You said you want to prove continuity by open sets, I highly doubt this is a homework exercise (if it is, it is a unpedagogical one). If it is a self-study problem, then you aren't "getting it." The point of proving theorems or partial results is to break a big problem into smaller more handleable pieces (every mathematician and scientist works this way in one form or another).

Notice that the function you are defining is *not* defined on the set where $x_2 = x_3$ and $y_2 = y_3.$ (Its domain is *not* $\mathbf{R}^6.$) It is continuous elsewhere for the reasons given above.

Comment: This was actually in the space $\mathbb{C}^3$ which is isomoprhic to $\mathbb{R}^6$. I failed to mention that in the post.  Each point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}^3$ are distinct $(x\neq y\neq z \neq x)$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$ I have $f(x,y,z)=(z-x)/(y-x)$, idk if this translates that in reals that each $x_1,x_2...$ are distinct too. But. it felt natural to go to $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ when proving continuity.

Comment: this is a homework problem, where I have to show that my function $f$ is a homeomorphism. I've already shown bijection and plan to show that $f$ is an open mapping to show that the preimage of $f$ exists and is also continuous.

Comment: also this is not the entire function, I've split it up into 3 components i.e $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$, $f_1,f_2$ i've sucsessfully shown that they are continuous, but its this $f_3=(z-x)/(y-x)=((x_1+iy_1)-(x_2+iy_2)/((x_3+iy_3)-(x_2+iy_2))$ and since I'm working on $\mathbb{R}^6$ . I'm only interested in $\Re{(f_3)}$

Comment: Even if $(x_i, y_i)$ _was_ a complex number, your function would still not be defined everywhere. Indeed, if $f(x,y,z) = (z-x)/(y-x)$ for complex numbers, then the function is defined on $\mathbf{C} \setminus \{x = y\}.$ And it is a rational function elsewhere, thus continuous.

Comment: How do you justify that it's rational elsewhere?

Comment: Follow the same pattern, the functions $\mathbf{z} \mapsto z_i$ from $\mathbf{C}^p \to \mathbf{C}$ are continuous, so are their sums, products and quotients (wherever the denominator is not zero...).